# Using cron to start a python script at every boot

Tags: python, cron

I tried using `cron` to start python script , at boot (as mentioned in the link).[Running a python script At Boot using cron](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/07/running-a-python-script-at-boot-using-cron/)

I made a python script `"hello.py"`:

```
#!usr/bin/env python 
import time
print "Hello World!"
time.sleep(10)
```

Then `chmod +x hello.py`.
I checked,if it running or not,it is giving me output.
I used `crontab -e` command and added the line `@reboot python /home/pi/hello.py &`.
Reboot using `sudo reboot` , but nothing happened! I am newbie .Although I read many discussions but I am not able to fix that!

Comment: how are you checking if your hello.py ran? because you won't see the printed "Hello World!". Try writing your "Hello World!" to a file and check if it's in the file ;-)

Comment: Or sleep for much longer ;-)

Comment: @Patrick I mean that if I ran that program on terminal using python hello.py it is running! and giving me output.

Comment: well the next thing i see is that the shebang is wrong: it is missing a / after !. other than that it's not really clear to me what you want :O

Comment: @doctorlove I used time.sleep because I read in some links that may be the programs output for a while and it vanishes. So I added this line to hold the output for a longer time.

Comment: @Patrick is right, the problem seems like that you don't know the difference between foreground process and background process. In your case, running "python hello.py" in terminal is running a foreground process, and you can see the output directly from terminal. The cron version is a background process, the output can not be seen directly(that's why it is "background"), you can modify(crontab -e) your job as: python hello.py > /tmp/result.txt, the output will be "redirect" to /tmp/result.txt, and it'll prove that your script ran.

Comment: @Patrick ! yes that's my mistake .Thanks for pointing  it :). (I don't use this shebang  before :p). But I read on a link that it might be a reason  that that program does not starts,so I added.

Comment: @wentao.Thank you for explaining so well! I don't know that thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when I want to verify whether a cronjob ran or not, I redirect all output to a log file like so:

```
12 0 * * * python /Path/To/File.py  > /Path/ToLog/log 2>&1
```

Then you can check this log timestamp and for its contents

Comment: Yes! as @wentao explained, I verified this! :)

Comment: Ahh I hadn't seen @wentao 's explanation.  It is spot on.  Notice that I also redirect stderr with the 2>&1    This will put all stderr and stdout into the same file, which might or might not be what you want